# Strange characters in AppleScript output

Tags: applescript, text-formatting

I have this AppleScript that returns the name of the currently playing artist in iTunes. Unfortunately, if the artist name contains special characters, like ú, bizarre characters are output. How can I fix this?

```
tell application "iTunes"
    if player state is playing then
        try
            set myTrack to artist of current track
        on error
            return ""
        end try
        return myTrack
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Unicode characters shouldn't normally cause any problems:

```
tell application "iTunes" to tell current track
    set name to "あ"
    name -- あ
end tell
```

The ID3 tags of some of your files probably have some non-Unicode encoding. I don't know how to deal with that from an AppleScript, but could you try converting the tags to UTF-8? See https://superuser.com/questions/90449/repair-encoding-of-id3-tags or http://code.google.com/p/id3-to-unicode/.

Comment: Isn't UTF-8 Apple's default? The issue remains even if I type the ú directly from the keyboard in the ID3 field box in iTunes.